# iPhone: Facebook FBDialog with pre-filled Message

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

Today I noticed that the code I have been using to display a FBDialog using the Facebook SDK, which shows a Dialog with a pre-filled Text isn't working anymore. It is just showing the dialog with an empty textfield. The text I want to show is missing.

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem, or is there a better way to pre-fill the textfield with a string?

This is the code I use to call the FBDialog:

```
NSString * message = @"Pre-filled Text";
NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: message,  @"message", nil];
[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: how did you end up fixing this?

Comment: I think best way would be to use the graph api, but that also means some effort for implementing the necessary views etc. I ended up posting a link. I think I used the pre filled text as the text of the link and left the additional field for user comments. Not the nicest solution, but was done in a few minutes.

Comment: So you made your URL the text? Like my URL would be for example: www.This is my app.com? Do you anything about how to do this via Graph API calls?

Comment: Also I just tried the Graph API and it seems that you cannot do it that way either. Facebook is really annoying! Anyway, just let me know more exactly on what you did so I can do something similar :)

Comment: If I remember correctly, you have three parameters: The uri, a text that describes the link, and a user edited text. The app posts its message as the text that describes the link. The user is still able to add a comment. However, you should be able to do it using graph api, as you simply call a url and provide all the information you want to post. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is intended behaviour. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

> `message`: **This field will be ignored on July 12, 2011** The message to prefill the text field that the user will type in. To be compliant with Facebook Platform Policies, your application may only set this field if the user manually generated the content earlier in the workflow. Most applications should not set this.

Comment: Damn. Just implemented that a few days ago. Is there any other way to define a text that the user may edit, that should be posted on the users facebook wall? Last resort I guess would be to create a ModalView that handles the text-editing and just send the message to the Graph API.

Comment: Yeah, Graph API direct calls is likely your best option for that.

Comment: Funny. They do not want apps to pre fill their dialogue so that user can approve the message. Apparently they want the user to write the message by hand. But funny is, that they push us toward graph interface, where the app can send a message completely without user interaction.

Comment: You can use 'description' but I believe you must also post 'name' and 'link' for it to appear.

Comment: @OhDannyBoy That still won't fill the "message" field.

Comment: That still won't fill the "message" field.